# Usage of 'rota' (scheduling planning tasks and responsibilities)

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, synonymes

*Rota*: a list of things that have to be done and of the people who will do them; : a fixed order of rotation (as of persons or duties).

> Companies would be expected to shift their rotas so that offices are never full unnecessarily.
>
> On s'attendrait à ce que les entreprises déplacent leurs rotations afin que les bureaux ne soient jamais remplis inutilement.

Can rotation be used to convey rota in this context? Is 'rota' used in professional French?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a native French speaker, I never heard *rota* to define what you are talking about (maybe it is used in some specific areas). However, we do use the word ***[roulement](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/roulement/70053)***:

> Succession de plusieurs personnes dans un travail qu'elles assurent à tour de rôle, selon un horaire fixé à l'avance : *Deux équipes qui travaillent par **roulement**.*

In your example, I would say something like:

> On s'attendrait à ce que les entreprises instaurent un **roulement** afin que les bureaux ne soient jamais remplis inutilement.

It is also quite common to see it in industrial vocabulary (from the same source):

> Fait, pour une quantité, un stock, d'être disponible pour une utilisation successive : *Assurer un **roulement** sur la semaine.*

I think the word "*rotation*" in French would also be correct, but it sounds less natural in this context and it doesn't convey the "work" meaning as much as "*roulement*" in my opinion.

Comment: Merci pour tes réponses !